# Unexpected token import - Electron/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

When I attempt to run my program after starting to learn **React**, I face this error when I ran my start script. I am importing the class 'App' from **app.js** to my entry point **main.js**.

Below is my code:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  target: "electron",
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 3333
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

**app.js:**

```
const React = require('react');

class App extends React.Component {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'key_here';

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
              container: 'map',
              style: 'map_style_here',
              center: [-74.50, 40],
              zoom: 9
           });
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default App
```

**main.js:**

```
'use strict';

const React    = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import App from './app';

const BrowserWindow = require('browser-window')
const app           = require("app");

var mainWindow = null;     // Keep global reference to main broswer window.

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
 if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
   app.quit();
 }
});

app.on('ready', function() {

 // Reference the main window object.
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 800});

 mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + "/app.html")

 mainWindow.on('closed', function() {

 // Dereference the main window object.
 mainWindow = null;

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('map'))
 })
})
```

**Error**:

```
Uncaught Exception:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:404:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
  at loadApplicationPackage  
(C:\Programming\RestaurantChat\node_modules\electron
prebuilt\dist\resources\default_app\main.js:257:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\Programming\RestaurantChat\node_modules\electron
prebuilt\dist\resources\default_app\main.js:289:5)
  at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Is there's something not compiling? I'm really at a loss for why there's a syntax error.

Comment: it would be very helpful to edit your question, what your syntax errors says and what line it is!

Comment: Don't know why I didn't include it in the first place - my bad! Give me a second to edit.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay before editing, had to take a phone call.

Comment: ok i think `import App from './app'` is the same as `var App = require('./app')`, that should fix your syntax error, but i am not sure about electron.

Comment: I tried testing that and it doesn't work, sadly. It returns an identical error message except the unexpected token is now '<'.

Comment: Sounds very likely that this is an issue with how you are compiling the JS. Are you using Webpack/Babel? Can you share your `webpack.config.js` file if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes little sense to use React in the main Electron process, the main process doesn't have access to the DOM. So, unless your plan is to render React components to string and then send the result to the renderer process via IPC you need to rethink your approach.

As for the `SyntaxError`, it looks like Babel isn't converting `import` to `require`, though I'm not sure if it's supposed to or if that's something that Webpack is supposed to handle. Are you using the [electron-renderer plugin](https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer)? You may want to start with the [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's my first time using the two together and I was thinking that using React in the main Electron process wouldn't be efficient. I'll try the plugin first thing in the morning and report back.

Comment: Once I changed my approach, Babel began to convert said keywords correctly. I'm assuming the issue was with the Electron main process not being able to access the DOM through ReactDOM. Thank you!